# Looking for a proof that $\pi$ is irrational using a series representation for it

Tags: nt.number-theory, irrational-numbers

This have been asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057980/looking-for-a-proof-that-pi-is-irrational-using-a-series-representation) but got no answers.

> I'm searching for a proof that $\pi$ is irrational using a series representation for $\pi$, but can't find it.

However, on this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_theorem) page show's that Apery's proof on the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ can be simplified to apply on $\zeta(2)$ which is better than what i'm looking for because it shows that $\pi^2$ is irrational. But I can't find this proof either. If it's was done, maybe no one ever published.

Comment: Check out van der Poorten's survey on Apery's proof "A proof that Euler missed" in Math. Intelligencer, as far as I remember it does $\zeta(2)$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

Beukers gave a proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(3)$ using Apery's ideas, expressed in integral form [here](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/11/3/268/339035?redirectedFrom=fulltext). This was published in 1979.

Comment: I've seen that but I'm interessed in proof's that uses fast convergent series.